# Is there a grid system that use percentage-based width for columns and px values for gutters?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, grid-layout

I'm looking for a grid solution that will be supported by IE11 which uses percentage-based column widths and px-based gutters. I'm looking for a grid layout with evenly spaced halves, thirds, quarters, sixths, and twelfths, in which the margin may vary depending on the breakpoint. Is this possible?

```
@import "compass/css3";

* {
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}

$pad: 20px;

.grid {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 0 $pad 0;

  &:after {
    /* Or @extend clearfix */
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}

[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
  padding-right: $pad;
  .grid &:last-of-type {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
.col-2-3 {
    width: 66.66%;
}
.col-1-3 {
    width: 33.33%;
}
.col-1-2 {
    width: 50%;
}
.col-1-4 {
    width: 25%;
}
.col-1-8 {
    width: 12.5%;
}

.module {
  padding: $pad;
  background: #eee;
}

/* Opt-in outside padding */
.grid-pad {
  padding: $pad 0 $pad $pad;
  [class*='col-']:last-of-type {
    padding-right: $pad;
  }
}

body {
    padding: 10px 50px 200px;
  background: url(https://s.cdpn.io/3/dark_wall_@2X.png);
  background-size: 300px 300px;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  em {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

Chris Coyier posted a solution, but it's a little wonky, because the gutters are defined by the right padding of the columns: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/eGcLw
Which means, the column widths are not accurate. For example, the first column of a 2 col layout will be less than 50% to account for the gutter, but the second column would be exactly 50% of the grid width, since it there is no right gutter on the last child.

I've had some issues with flex and grid layouts with IE11, so I plan on just using floated block elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with. I'm not a math guy, so I can't tell you why these width equations work, or if there's a better algorithm.

https://codepen.io/richiegarcia/pen/YBEVQR

```
.grid {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #8181ac;
}

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
  background: #cfcfcf;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.grid [class*=col-]:last-of-type { margin-right: 0; }

.col-1-2 { width: calc(100% * 1 / 2 - 20px / 2); }
.col-1-3 { width: calc(100% * 1 / 3 - 20px / 1.5); }
.col-1-4 { width: calc(100% * 1 / 4 - 20px / 1.33); }
.col-1-6 { width: calc(100% * 1 / 6 - 20px / 1.2); }
.col-1-12 { width: calc(100% * 1 / 12 - 20px / 1.09); }
```

Comment: From your last post, I can see that you had posted the solution. It will be helpful to other community members in future, If you try to mark the helpful answer as an accepted answer. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks! Will do, as soon as I'm able.

Answer (score 1):

The final code will depend on the kind of grid you want exactly, but maybe this will help you:

```css
.grid {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #8181ac;
}

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Let's assume that the gap = 20px */

[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
  background: #cfcfcf;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.grid [class*=col-]:last-of-type { margin-right: -20px; }

.col-1-2 { width: calc(100% * 1 / 2 - 20px / (2 / 1)); }

.col-1-3 { width: calc(100% * 1 / 3 - 20px / (3 / 2)); }
.col-2-3 { width: calc(100% * 2 / 3 - 20px / (3 / 1)); }

.col-1-4 { width: calc(100% * 1 / 4 - 20px / (4 / 3)); }
.col-2-4 { width: calc(100% * 2 / 4 - 20px / (4 / 2)); }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
   <div class="col-1-2"><h3>1/2</h3></div>
   <div class="col-1-2"><h3>1/2</h3></div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
   <div class="col-1-3"><h3>1/3</h3></div>
   <div class="col-1-3"><h3>1/3</h3></div>
   <div class="col-1-3"><h3>1/3</h3></div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
   <div class="col-1-3"><h3>1/3</h3></div>
   <div class="col-2-3"><h3>2/3</h3></div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
   <div class="col-1-4"><h3>1/4</h3></div>
   <div class="col-1-4"><h3>1/4</h3></div>
   <div class="col-1-4"><h3>1/4</h3></div>
   <div class="col-1-4"><h3>1/4</h3></div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
   <div class="col-1-4"><h3>1/4</h3></div>
   <div class="col-2-4"><h3>2/4</h3></div>
   <div class="col-1-4"><h3>1/4</h3></div>
</div>
```

With a SCSS syntax, on the example above the col `width` is calculated this way:

```
calc(100% * #{$colSize} / #{$gridSize} - #{$gap} / (#{$gridSize} / (#{$gridSize} - #{$colSize})));
```

And the gap is set with `margin-right` on `[class*='col-']`.

You can of course write a mixin to create the selectors dynamically:

```
$gap: 20px;
$maxGridCol: 5;

@for $i from 1 through $maxGridCol {
   @for $y from 1 through $i {
      [class*="col-#{$y}-#{$i}"] {
         width: calc(100% * #{$y} / #{$i} - (#{$gap} / (#{$i} - #{$y})));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This works nicely for two column rows, but I need a grid split into thirds, quarters, sixths and twelfths as well. Your solution was very helpful and I tweaked it to serve my purpose.

Comment: @oaklandrichie I was so confident in my code that I didn't test with more columns! You are right, my calculations are wrong. The corrections you made seems to be a step in the right direction but doesn't work in every cases (but again, maybe it is enough for what you need to do). Anyway, I just edited my answer if a more complexe equation and I think it will work in every case now. :) I am not very good at maths either, so maybe there is an easier way to calculate the width?

Comment: Yes, I believe my solution only works for evenly split rows (no mixing and matching col widths). However, my grid allows for different gutter widths as well. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @oaklandrichie You're very welcome! Please consider accepting either yours or my answer if it solved your problem (just click on the checkmark next to the answer). :)

Comment: My mistake: your solution works for different gutter widths as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your colsize in percentage in the database, you can use this convert to change it to col-size.

```php
$col_size = (isset($col_size_percentage) ? ($col_size_percentage / 100) * 12 : 12);
```

this is PHP and a oneliner.

```html
<div class="col-md-<?= $col_size ?>"> Your size div </div>
```